# Как сделать изображение, подстраивающееся под размеры блока?

Tags: css

Есть DIV, размеры которого вычисляются через js. Высота и ширина у блока фиксированные. Какие стили нужно прописать изображению, которые находится в блоке,
чтобы изображение подстраивалось под размеры блока (было пропорционально уменьшено)?

Comment: какой-нибудь фреймворк используете? Bootstrap, например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без кода ответить сложно, но вобщем-то Вам надо дать ширину в процентах: `width: 100%;`

Также, если есть возможность выяснить размеры картинки, то хорошо бы еще указать `max-width: [amount]px;`, чтобы картинка не располхалась больше своего значения...

Во всем этом есть один минус - высота картинки будет пропорционально меняться, и, в зависимости от размеров блока, может влиять на форматирование страницы в целом - будет вылезать за блок, или на оборот, слишко много места пустого в блоке.

Вобщем все сводится к тому, что такие вопросы надо ВСЕГДА задавать, прилагая пример кода, и лучше fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте изображение гибким, должно помочь:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```